# C++ attributes private access

Tags: c++, attributes, private

I have a class Sphere (.ccp and .h) which has some attributs declared as private. I read that these attributs can be used by the class itself, but when I try to use one attribut in the Sphere.cpp, its says "use of non declared identifier".

Sphere.h:

```
class Sphere {
public:
    inline Sphere () {}
    inline Sphere (const Vec3Df spherePos, const float radius, const Material2 & mat) :       spherePos(spherePos), radius(radius), mat (mat) {
    updateBoundingBox();
    }
    virtual ~Sphere ()
    {}

    inline const Vec3Df  getSpherePos () const { return spherePos; }
    inline Vec3Df getSpherePos () { return spherePos; }

    inline const float getRadius () { return radius; }

    inline const Material2 & getMaterial () const { return mat; }
    inline Material2 & getMaterial () { return mat; }

    inline const BoundingBox & getBoundingBox () const { return bbox; }
    void updateBoundingBox ();

    bool intersect(Ray ray);

private:
    Vec3Df spherePos;
    float radius;
    Material2 mat;
    BoundingBox bbox;

};
```

And I call attributs like this:

```
Vec3Df pointGauche = spherePos;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you within a member function ?

Comment: "Class" and "file" are different things.

Comment: @EricFortin Yes, the call is in the function updateboundingBox in the .cpp

Comment: Can you show us the function definition in the cpp? (updateBoundingBox)

Comment: @otisonoza It's void updateBoundingBox(){ }

Comment: @otisonoza I realized that I didn't put Sphere in front of updateBoundingBox. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Private class members are only accessible from members of the class:

```
struct Foo
{
    static void bar(Foo &);
    int zoo() const;

private:
    int x;
    typedef void * type;
    type gobble(type);
};

void * Foo::gobble(void * q)
{
   x = 10;          // OK
   type p = q;      // OK
}

void Foo::bar(Foo & rhs)
{
    rhs.x += 10;    // OK
    type p = &rhs;  // OK
    rhs.zip();      // OK 
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    // f.x += 20;       // Error, Foo::x inaccessible
    // Foo::type p;     // Error, Foo::type inaccesible
    // f.gobble(NULL);  // Error, Foo::gobble inaccessible
    Foo::bar(x);        // OK, Foo::bar is public
    return x.zoo();     // OK, Foo::zoo is public
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which class `void updateBoundingBox()` belongs to:

```
// note the Sphere:: part
void Sphere::updateBoundingBox() {

    // now you have access to private instance variables:
    Vec3Df pointGauche = spherePos; 
    Vec3Df pointDroit; 
    Vec3Df pointHaut; 
    Vec3Df pointBas; 
    bbox = BoundingBox(spherePos); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is wrong:

```
void updateBoundingBox(){ Vec3Df pointGauche = spherePos; Vec3Df pointDroit; Vec3Df pointHaut; Vec3Df pointBas; bbox = BoundingBox(spherePos); }
```

Try this way:

```
void Sphere::updateBoundingBox()
{
Vec3Df pointGauche = spherePos;
Vec3Df pointDroit;
Vec3Df pointHaut;
Vec3Df pointBas;
bbox = BoundingBox(spherePos);
}
```